# Cannot select form option on iPhone

Tags: ios, forms, select

The following code works fine with Firefox and Safari on Mac OS:

```
<form style="text-align: center;" method="get" action="overview.php" target="_blank">
  <select name="massif" onclick="this.form.submit();">
  <option value="Bauges">Aravis, Bauges, Bornes</option>
  <option value="Beaufortain">Beaufortain</option>
  <option value="Belledonne">Belledonne</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

In fact, for Firefox I don't eve need the line

```
<input value="Submit" type="submit">
```

but it is necessary for Safari.

However, for Safari on iOS 14.6 on iPhone, the first option in the list is immediately launched, without selecting one of the options.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

James

Answer (score 1):

OK I thinks I've found a solution, which is to replace the line:

```
<select name="massif" onclick="this.form.submit();">
```

by

```
<select name="massif" onchange="this.form.submit();">
```

However, I still need the "Submit" button for use with Safari, but not for Firefox.

James